# Ubuntu + Nginx 127.0.0.1 works but localhost doesn't

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, localhost

this one is weird, because I don't have any error messages.

I have a very basic default file:

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/default.access_log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/default.error_log warn;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc {
            root /usr/share;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location /images {
            root /usr/share;
            autoindex off;
    }
```

Now, in shell,

```
ping localhost
```

is fine.

However, in any browser, it displays an error. Chrome, for instance says: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost".

127.0.0.1 on the other hand works in browsers.

Maybe you know where should I **check for errors?** Nothing in /var/log and other files are clean....

Comment: Does `telnet localhost 80` from a shell work? How about `curl http://localhost`?

Comment: Another thing that can trip this up is if you have an ipv6 address. On OSX 8 localhost is routed to the ipv6 address. Compiling Nginx with `--with-ipv6` and adding the the this listen directive `listen [::1]:80` will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! In deed nslookup isn't relevant, thanks @Mark! So I tried

```
sudo ping localhost
```

and got a correct answer.

Finally chmod'ed **/etc/hosts** to 644 and now everything is working. Although, not sure whether 644 is the best thing to chmod to.

Another thing, I have no idea why initially the permissions on **/etc/hosts** were

```
-rw------- 1 root root 278 2011-12-02 22:52 /etc/hosts
```

but now it's kind of irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `ping` is completely relevant to NGINX, you can ping any server that will respond to ping requests regardless of the services running.

Check;

`curl -I -v http://127.0.0.1/` - Will see if the site is accessible by local address

`curl -I -v http://localhost/` - Will see if the site is accessible by local hostname

`curl -I -v http://serverhostname/` - Will see if the site is accessible by servers hostname

`nslookup localhost` - Make sure 'localhost' is resolving to 127.0.0.1

Post the output of that and if you're still having issues we can give you more guidance

Comment: sam, thank you! Yep! curl was fine - it gave 200 OK answer for localhost and 127.0.0.1.

But:

root@valk-pc:~# nslookup localhost
Server:  11.0.0.138
Address: 11.0.0.138#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find localhost: No answer


This is the address of the router. But my /etc/hosts file contains 

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

From the other place, I read that hosts file is irrelevant though.

Comment: @valk That would be your issue, do you have an entry for localhost in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I do have. I edited my previous reply. /etc/hosts is: 

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 valk-pc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

Comment: nslookup does not use /etc/hosts file, it rather uses the nameservers listed in the /etc/resolv.conf file. (hence people tend to add a localhost entry to their dns entry's)

Comment: I think he means irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. Was able to connect to a server on 127.0.0.1 but not using localhost. This configuration solved it for me (especially the server_name part).

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    ...
}
```